# Qt 5 - How to make QThread exit from its `wait` function where it got stuck after executing a QProcess on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qthread, qprocess

I believe I've found a bug in the Windows' Qt 5 implementation. It doesn't reproduce with Qt 6, so I don't think I should post it to Qt's maintainers now. But still I'd like to ask here (1) if it's a bug indeed (or is my code just incorrect somewhere), and (2) what workaround can I write to avoid this issue, provided that I can't upgrade to Qt 6 right now.

I have a class `BackgroundExecutor` which owns a `QThread` and has a function for posting new tasks (`std::function` instances) to it. In its destructor, `BackgroundExecutor` calls `quit` and `wait` member functions of its thread object.

Things get interesting when one of the posted tasks processed by the background `QThread` happens to have executed some external `QProcess` (I think it affects the state of the thread's `QEventLoop` somehow). In this case, the `wait` call on a `QThread` has a chance to hang forever.

The call stack of the main thread looks like this:

```
    ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()  Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx() Unknown
>   Qt5Cored.dll!QThread::wait(QDeadlineTimer deadline) Line 630    C++
    QThreadAndQProcessBug.exe!BackgroundExecutor::~BackgroundExecutor() Line 87 C++
    QThreadAndQProcessBug.exe!RunTest() Line 123    C++
    QThreadAndQProcessBug.exe!RunTestMultipleTimes() Line 132   C++
```

And here's the call stack of the background thread:

```
    win32u.dll!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() Unknown
    user32.dll!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()    Unknown
>   Qt5Cored.dll!QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 625    C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 140   C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 232    C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QThread::exec() Line 547   C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QThread::run() Line 617    C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QThreadPrivate::start(void * arg) Line 407 C++
```

It's stuck at the line 625 (as of Qt 5.15.2) of *"qeventdispatcher_win.cpp"*, inside the `QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents` function: `waitRet = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(nCount, pHandles, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT, MWMO_ALERTABLE | MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);`.

The full text of the program which reproduces the issue (though it might take some time - one of my PCs requires only 1000 iterations on average, while the other one might execute 100'000 iterations before the hang would occur):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QThread>

#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::function<void()>); // for passing std::function<void()> through Qt's signals

static void EnsureStdFunctionOfVoidMetaTypeRegistered()
{
  static std::once_flag std_function_metatype_registered{};
  std::call_once(std_function_metatype_registered, []() {
    qRegisterMetaType<std::function<void()>>("std::function<void()>");
    });
}

class WorkerObject; // worker object that "lives" in a background thread of a BackgroundExecutor

class BackgroundExecutor final
{
public:
  BackgroundExecutor();
  ~BackgroundExecutor();

  // posts a new task for the background QThread,
  // returns a std::future which can be waited on to ensure the task is done
  [[nodiscard]] std::future<void> PostTask(std::function<void()> task);

private:
  WorkerObject* _background_worker = nullptr;
  QThread* _qt_thread = nullptr;
};

class WorkerObject final : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT;

public:
  WorkerObject()
  {
    connect(this, &WorkerObject::TaskPosted, this, &WorkerObject::ProcessPostedTask);
  }

  // can be called from any thread;
  // "moves" the task to the background worker thread via Qt's signals/slots mechanism
  // so that it could be processed there
  void PostTask(const std::function<void()>& task)
  {
    EnsureStdFunctionOfVoidMetaTypeRegistered();
    Q_EMIT TaskPosted(task);
  }

private Q_SLOTS:
  void ProcessPostedTask(const std::function<void()>& posted_task)
  {
    std::invoke(posted_task);
  }

Q_SIGNALS:
  void TaskPosted(const std::function<void()>&);
};

BackgroundExecutor::BackgroundExecutor()
{
  {
    std::unique_ptr<QThread> qt_thread_safe(new QThread()); // exception safety
    _background_worker = new WorkerObject();
    _qt_thread = qt_thread_safe.release();
  }

  _background_worker->moveToThread(_qt_thread);

  QObject::connect(_qt_thread, &QThread::finished, _background_worker, &WorkerObject::deleteLater);
  QObject::connect(_qt_thread, &QThread::finished, _qt_thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

  _qt_thread->start();
}

BackgroundExecutor::~BackgroundExecutor()
{
  _qt_thread->quit();
  _qt_thread->wait(); // !!! might hang !!!
}

[[nodiscard]] std::future<void> BackgroundExecutor::PostTask(std::function<void()> task)
{
  std::shared_ptr task_promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<void>>();
  std::future task_future = task_promise->get_future();

  std::function<void()> task_wrapper = [task_promise = std::move(task_promise), task = std::move(task)]()
  {
    std::invoke(task);
    task_promise->set_value();
  };

  _background_worker->PostTask(task_wrapper);
  return task_future;
}

static void RunQProcessAndWaitForFinished()
{
  QProcess process;
  process.setProgram("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
  process.setArguments({ "/C", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\timeout.exe", QString::number(30) });

  process.start();
  process.waitForStarted(-1);
  process.waitForFinished(-1);
}

static void RunTest()
{
  BackgroundExecutor executor;
  std::future task_future = executor.PostTask([]() {
    RunQProcessAndWaitForFinished();
    });
  task_future.get();
}

static void RunTestMultipleTimes()
{
  constexpr int repeat = 500'000;
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "starting iteration " << i << '\n';
    RunTest();
  }
  std::cout << "all iterations finished" << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QCoreApplication qt_app{ argc, argv };

  QTimer::singleShot(
    0,
    [&]()
    {
      RunTestMultipleTimes();
      qt_app.exit(0);
    });

  return qt_app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Did you try to set `Qt::QueuedConnection` in `WorkerObject` ctor explicitly?

WorkerObject()
  {
    connect(this, &WorkerObject::TaskPosted, this, &WorkerObject::ProcessPostedTask, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  }

Comment: You should also check newer versions of Qt5 - latest opensource release is 5.15.5

Comment: @Alexey  Yes, I tried that. It made no difference since the `WorkerObject` already belongs to the background thread (I call `moveToThread` immediately after creating it) -- thus the signal is sent as if via `QueuedConnection` in this particular case.

Comment: I even tried `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(_background_worker, "ProcessPostedTask", Qt::QueuedConnection)` :)  But still no difference, the problem isn't there.

Comment: @Osyotr  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it (somehow missed versions newer than 5.15.2 in Qt Installer, it didn't show them to me by default).

Comment: @Osyotr  It seems that the bug has been fixed in 5.15.5. At least, I couldn't reproduce it with this Qt version (tried both msvc2017 and msvc2019 toolsets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question, I also ran some tests with Qt 5.12.12 and Qt 5.15.5, as suggested in the comments. I could reproduce the bug in neither of these versions, while in Qt 5.15.2 it continues to reproduce consistently. This could either mean that the bug is really absent in these versions, or that it is much more rarely reproducible there (at least on my PCs) and I didn't try enough.

In any case, I would like to share a workaround which I came up with after consulting one of my colleagues who has more experience with WinAPI than I do. Hope it will also help someone else in the future, if they happen to be stuck with the Qt version where this bug is present.

Here's the code (you can compare it with the original listing from the question using a tool such as WinMerge, or just look at all the parts near the `WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT` macro):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QThread>

#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT 1

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>
#endif // _WIN32

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::function<void()>); // for passing std::function<void()> through Qt's signals

static void EnsureStdFunctionOfVoidMetaTypeRegistered()
{
  static std::once_flag std_function_metatype_registered{};
  std::call_once(std_function_metatype_registered, []() {
    qRegisterMetaType<std::function<void()>>("std::function<void()>");
    });
}

class WorkerObject; // worker object that "lives" in a background thread of a BackgroundExecutor

class BackgroundExecutor final
{
public:
  BackgroundExecutor();
  ~BackgroundExecutor();

  // posts a new task for the background QThread,
  // returns a std::future which can be waited on to ensure the task is done
  [[nodiscard]] std::future<void> PostTask(std::function<void()> task);

private:
  WorkerObject* _background_worker = nullptr;
  QThread* _qt_thread = nullptr;
};

class WorkerObject final : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT;

public:
  WorkerObject()
  {
    connect(this, &WorkerObject::TaskPosted, this, &WorkerObject::ProcessPostedTask);
  }

  // can be called from any thread;
  // "moves" the task to the background worker thread via Qt's signals/slots mechanism
  // so that it could be processed there
  void PostTask(const std::function<void()>& task)
  {
    EnsureStdFunctionOfVoidMetaTypeRegistered();
    Q_EMIT TaskPosted(task);
  }

#if WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT
  [[nodiscard]] DWORD GetBackgroundThreadID() const
  {
    while (_windows_thread_id_initialized.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == false)
      std::this_thread::yield();
    return _windows_thread_id;
  }
#endif // WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT

public Q_SLOTS:
  void InitializeBackgroundThreadID()
  {
#if WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT
    _windows_thread_id = ::GetCurrentThreadId();
    _windows_thread_id_initialized.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
#else
    assert(false && "shouldn't have been invoked in this configuration");
#endif // WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT
  }

  void ProcessPostedTask(const std::function<void()>& posted_task)
  {
    std::invoke(posted_task);
  }

Q_SIGNALS:
  void TaskPosted(const std::function<void()>&);

#if WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT
private:
  DWORD _windows_thread_id;
  std::atomic<bool> _windows_thread_id_initialized{ false };
#endif // WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT
};

BackgroundExecutor::BackgroundExecutor()
{
  {
    std::unique_ptr<QThread> qt_thread_safe(new QThread()); // exception safety
    _background_worker = new WorkerObject();
    _qt_thread = qt_thread_safe.release();
  }

  _background_worker->moveToThread(_qt_thread);

#if WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(_background_worker, "InitializeBackgroundThreadID", Qt::QueuedConnection);
#endif // WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT

  QObject::connect(_qt_thread, &QThread::finished, _background_worker, &WorkerObject::deleteLater);
  QObject::connect(_qt_thread, &QThread::finished, _qt_thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

  _qt_thread->start();
}

BackgroundExecutor::~BackgroundExecutor()
{
  _qt_thread->quit();
#if WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT
  const DWORD background_thread_id = _background_worker->GetBackgroundThreadID();
  while (_qt_thread->wait(1'000) == false)
    // "awaken" the MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx function call in which the background thread got stuck
    // by posting a fake "message" to it, so that it would snap out of it, check its exit flag and finish properly
    ::PostThreadMessage(background_thread_id, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
#else
  _qt_thread->wait();
#endif // WORKAROUND_FOR_QTHREAD_WAIT
}

[[nodiscard]] std::future<void> BackgroundExecutor::PostTask(std::function<void()> task)
{
  std::shared_ptr task_promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<void>>();
  std::future task_future = task_promise->get_future();

  std::function<void()> task_wrapper = [task_promise = std::move(task_promise), task = std::move(task)]()
  {
    std::invoke(task);
    task_promise->set_value();
  };

  _background_worker->PostTask(task_wrapper);
  return task_future;
}

static void RunQProcessAndWaitForFinished()
{
  QProcess process;
  process.setProgram("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
  process.setArguments({ "/C", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\timeout.exe", QString::number(30) });

  process.start();
  process.waitForStarted(-1);
  process.waitForFinished(-1);
}

static void RunTest()
{
  BackgroundExecutor executor;
  std::future task_future = executor.PostTask([]() {
    RunQProcessAndWaitForFinished();
    });
  task_future.get();
}

static void RunTestMultipleTimes()
{
  constexpr int repeat = 500'000;
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "starting iteration " << i << '\n';
    RunTest();
  }
  std::cout << "all iterations finished" << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QCoreApplication qt_app{ argc, argv };

  QTimer::singleShot(
    0,
    [&]()
    {
      RunTestMultipleTimes();
      qt_app.exit(0);
    });

  return qt_app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

---

And now for the implementation details.

The basic idea is: the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(..., QS_ALLINPUT, ...)` function call (in which the background thread gets stuck) can be "awakened" by a message posted to this thread's queue, since `QS_ALLINPUT` also implies `QS_POSTMESSAGE` as a part of its *"wake mask"*. This can be done by calling `PostThreadMessage` from the destroying (main) thread in case we've detected that the background one got stuck. And since we don't care about a particular type of a message (and actually don't want to send any "meaningful" message), `WM_NULL` will do the trick.

So, the destructor of our `BackgroundExecutor` class should look like this:

```
BackgroundExecutor::~BackgroundExecutor()
{
  _qt_thread->quit();

  const DWORD background_thread_id = _background_worker->GetBackgroundThreadID();
  while (_qt_thread->wait(1'000) == false)
    ::PostThreadMessage(background_thread_id, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
}
```

Now the question is, how do we get this `DWORD background_thread_id` value. Qt doesn't provide us an easy way of getting it from a `QThread` object (there is a function `currentThreadId`, but it is `static` and returns a `DWORD` ID of the *currently executing* thread, thus it's not what we want here). Instead, we will call `GetCurrentThreadId` from the background thread at some early point of its execution, store it in our `WorkerObject`, and retrieve in the main thread later.

In order to do that, we can write a new slot `InitializeBackgroundThreadID` in the `WorkerObject` class and invoke it via `Qt::QueuedConnection` from the `BackgroundExecutor`'s constructor after moving the worker object to the background thread (thus ensuring that the slot will be invoked from that thread):

```
public Q_SLOTS:
  void InitializeBackgroundThreadID()
  {
    _windows_thread_id = ::GetCurrentThreadId();
    _windows_thread_id_initialized.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
  }
```

(here, `_windows_thread_id` is a `DWORD` member variable of the `WorkerObject`, while `_windows_thread_id_initialized` is a `std::atomic<bool>` guard flag required for cross-thread synchronization via the [*synchronizes-with*](https://preshing.com/20130823/the-synchronizes-with-relation/) relation)

In `BackgroundExecutor`'s constructor:

```
  ...
  _background_worker->moveToThread(_qt_thread);
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(_background_worker, "InitializeBackgroundThreadID", Qt::QueuedConnection);
  ...
```

Now we can implement the getter for this thread ID:

```
  [[nodiscard]] DWORD GetBackgroundThreadID() const
  {
    while (_windows_thread_id_initialized.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == false)
      std::this_thread::yield();
    return _windows_thread_id;
  }
```

In practice, by the time the `BackgroundExecutor`'s destructor is called, the thread ID will have been already initialized, so the loop won't spin or call `yield` at all: it is just needed to guarantee the *synchronizes-with* relation (the main thread will be guaranteed to read the correct value of `_windows_thread_id` *after* it has read `true` from `_windows_thread_id_initialized` via a *load-acquire* operation).

There can be other means of implementing this part, e.g., we could make the `DWORD _windows_thread_id` member variable an `atomic` itself, providing it some "invalid" sentry value for the "uninitialized" state ([Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040223-00/?p=40503) once wrote zero should be okay for that). But these are just the implementation details, the basic idea still remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 5.12.12, all iterations are complete. Did you try this version?

I just split classes into separate files to implicitly include the moc file and I made a .pro file.

```
QT += core

CONFIG += c++17 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    backgroundexecutor.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    workerobject.cpp

HEADERS += \
    backgroundexecutor.h \
    workerobject.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: No, I haven't tried older Qt 5 versions yet. Indeed, it could be that the bug was introduced later and the previous versions didn't have it -- however, downgrading just because of this one rare bug is not a very good option for me (I already found a workaround, will post it here later). Also, I really hope that splitting classes to separate files and/or implicitly including _moc_ shouldn't matter in such cases, otherwise that would be weird: Qt is supposed to allow my approach as well.

Comment: @Taras Did you try another computer or Windows version? I don't thing it is related to Qt and your code is fine to me.

Comment: I tried two computers: 1) Windows 10 Pro version 20H2, Intel Core i9-10900X CPU @ 3.70 GHz; 2) Windows 10 Pro version 2004, AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor @ 3.60 GHz. On the first one, the bug reproduces quite often, every 1000 iterations on average. On the second one, it is a much rarer case: once per 100'000 iterations or so, mostly in Debug builds (on this machine, it's very hard to reproduce the bug in Release builds, I got it only once since yesterday, -- but still it *is* reproducible).

Comment: I also believe that the issue is related to Qt 5's implementation of class `QEventDispatcherWin32`. There is a handle called `d->winEventNotifierActivatedEvent` which is waited on in that `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call where the thread hangs. Normally, it is not present and remains _nullptr_. But when a `QProcess` is created in the current background thread, it assigns this handle to the thread's event dispatcher, thus affecting the waiting logic somehow. I'm not sure how exactly, but without having executed a `QProcess` in the background thread, this hang never occurred.

Comment: @Taras ok, I will try with your Qt 5.15.2.

Comment: @Taras I am stuck in the 17th iteration with Qt 5.15.2 aha!

Comment: Indeed, I was running the tests with Qt 5.12.12 all night, and the hang never reproduced. So, most likely, it's a bug that was introduced after Qt 5.12.